# Javascript and CSS: create buttons from array with different icons

Tags: javascript

In my application, I have an array with three entries. Based on each entry, I want to create a button, so three buttons altogether.

```
    let arrayButtons = [
        {
            title: "Mike",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Mike.png\'',
        },
        {
            title: "Hopper",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Hopper.png\'',
        },
        {
            title: "Elfi",
            source: "http://www.cnn.com",
            icon: '\'./dashboardresources/Icon_Elfi.png\'',
        }
    ]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayButtons.length; i++) {
        let buttonTitle = arrayButtons[i].title;
        let buttonImagePath = arrayButtons[i].icon; // this is the path I want to use

        const buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");

        buttons.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            "<div><button class='changeButton'>" +
            // How do I use buttonImagePath to set the background url in the class selector?
            "<i class='icon'></i>" + buttonTitle + "</button></div>"
        );
    }
```

And finally, the corresponding CSS selector:

```
    .icon {
        // currently hard coded here. How do I dynamically change the url based on the array entries above?
        background: url('./resources/Icon_Mike.png') no-repeat;
    }
```

So in the end, there should be three buttons:

1.) with title "Mike" and icon "Icon_Mike"

2.) with title "Hopper" and icon "Icon_Hopper"

3.) with title "Elfi" and icon "Icon_Elfi"

I googled so much and only found solutions with "onClick" for buttons. Can you please help me? Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Its because currently, all three buttons have the same icon, which is set in .icon as background url. Goal is that every button has a different icon (Icon_Mike for one button, Icon_Hopper for the second button, Icon_Elfi for the third button)

Comment: With JS using a HTML string? I'd inline the url into a style attribute. It's not "nice", but it will work. `style='background-image: url(" + buttonImagePath + ")'`

Comment: if I understand correctly you are looking for something like that https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp, am I right ? 
like buttons.style. background = buttonImagePath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the part

```
"<i class='icon'></i>" + buttonTitle + "</button></div>"
```

With

```
"<i style=\"background: url('" + buttonImagePath + "') no-repeat;\"></i>" + buttonTitle + "</button></div>"
```

If your icons already have the *'* around, try this:

```
"<i style=\"background: url(" + buttonImagePath + ") no-repeat;\"></i>" + buttonTitle + "</button></div>"
```

Comment: This will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It gives the warning: "Cannot resolve file" "

Comment: And it says "no-repeat is not allowed here" >.<

Comment: Edited in the answer. Your icons have urls with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate dynamic CSS rules via JS (instead of an inline `style` within each `<i>` tag), you could do that with a `<style>` tag placed inside the `<head>` section.

Then the JS code would generate distinct class-names for each icon (e.g. `icon_Mike`), and for each one it would append the CSS rule inside `style#icons-bg` (during the same `for` cycle as the one injecting the icons inside `#buttons`).

The result would look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>

  <style id="icons-bg">
    .icon_Mike { background-image: url('./dashboardresources/Icon_Mike.png') }
    .icon_Hopper { background-image: url('./dashboardresources/Icon_Hopper.png') }
    .icon_Elfi { background-image: url('./dashboardresources/Icon_Elfi.png') }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="buttons">
    <div><button class='changeButton'><i class='icon icon_Mike'></i>Mike</button></div>
    <div><button class='changeButton'><i class='icon icon_Hopper'></i>Hopper</button></div>
    <div><button class='changeButton'><i class='icon icon_Elfi'></i>Elfi</button></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```